# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have some arrays and I want to remove arrays which all elements equal to Zeros.

> 0[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   1[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   2[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   3[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   4[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   5[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   6[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>   7[0.152, 0.253, 0.102, 0.304, 0.355, 0.355, 0.152, 0.203, 0.203]
>   8[0.135, 0.135, 0.135, 0.325, 0.325, 0.325, 0.189, 0.189, 0.189]
>   9[0.302, 0.302, 0.302, 0.755, 0.755, 0.755, 0.453, 0.453, 0.453]
>   10[0.209, 0.209, 0.209, 0.546, 0.546, 0.546, 0.337, 0.337, 0.337]
>   11[0.339, 0.527, 0.433, 0.791, 0.904, 0.941, 0.49, 0.584, 0.584]
>   12[0.262, 0.262, 0.262, 0.669, 0.669, 0.669, 0.407, 0.407, 0.407]
>   13[0.054, 0.054, 0.054, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.108, 0.108, 0.108]
>   14[0.19, 0.228, 0.19, 0.418, 0.456, 0.418, 0.266, 0.342, 0.266]
>   15[0.067, 0.067, 0.067, 0.132, 0.132, 0.132, 0.067, 0.067, 0.067]
>   16[0.321, 0.581, 0.441, 0.681, 0.842, 0.882, 0.421, 0.541, 0.541]
>   17[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

And I tried to write the code one by Array list and one by 2D-Array but I always get errors.

This code when i tried to use ArrayList;

```
int binningNumber = 19;
int numberOfPixels = angle.getHeight() * angle.getWidth();

ArrayList<float[]> allVectors = new ArrayList<float[]>();

for(int i=0;i<angle.getHeight();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<angle.getWidth();j++)
    {
        float angleVal = angle.get(i, j);
        float magnitudeVal = magnitude.get(i, j);
        float[] input2 = new float[19];
        input2 = zeroVectorBinning(angleVal,magnitudeVal,binningNumber);
        allVectors.add(input2);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < allVectors.size(); i++) {
    if (isZeros(allVectors.get(i))) {
        allVectors.remove(i);
    }
}


/*****************Remove Zero elements Method ****************/
private static boolean isZeros(float[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And those are errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at boofcv.ExampleInterestPoint.preSmoothing(ExampleInterestPoint.java:316)
    at boofcv.ExampleInterestPoint.getInerestPointsChunks(ExampleInterestPoint.java:173)
    at boofcv.ExampleInterestPoint.main(ExampleInterestPoint.java:668)
```

And this code when i tried to use 2D Array

```
int numberOfPixels = angle.getHeight() * angle.getWidth();
int binningNumber = 19;

float[][] allVectors = new float [numberOfPixels][binningNumber];
float[][] allVectorsOfZeros = new float [numberOfPixels][binningNumber];
int index = 0;
float[] input2 = new float[19];
for(int i=0;i<angle.getHeight();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<angle.getWidth();j++)
    {
        float angleVal = angle.get(i, j);
        float magnitudeVal = magnitude.get(i, j);                       
        input2 = zeroVectorBinning(angleVal,magnitudeVal,binningNumber);
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < input2.length; i1++) {
            if (input2[i1] != 0) {
                allVectors[index++] =input2;
            }
            else
            {
                allVectorsOfZeros[index++] =input2;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It always gives me those errors,

I have two 2D arrays one for arrays which all elements equal zeros
and another for arrays which have values.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at boofcv.ExampleInterestPoint.preSmoothing(ExampleInterestPoint.java:297)
    at boofcv.ExampleInterestPoint.getInerestPointsChunks(ExampleInterestPoint.java:170
    at boofcv.ExampleInterestPoint.main(ExampleInterestPoint.java:660)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: On line 297 of `ExampleInterestPoint.java` (is that file really 660+ lines long??) you try to access `array[9]` on an array of length 9, indexed from 0 to 8.

Comment: @assylias 
yes it's along project ...

should  i Minimize the loop or what ??

thanks assylias

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're asking some index in array that not exists... With your code provided can't figure out exacly which is it...

In order to ask your question, i've done a method that checks if there are only zeros in an array... here [is the demo](https://ideone.com/3qLFeM).

```
private static final Float ZERO = 0f;

private static void checkIfZeros(float[] simpleArray) {
    boolean moreThanZeros = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < simpleArray.length; i++) {
        // check if there are only zeros
        if (!Float.valueOf(simpleArray[i]).equals(Float.valueOf(ZERO)))
        {
            moreThanZeros = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(moreThanZeros)
        System.out.println("ARRAY WITH MORE THAN ZEROS");
    else
        System.out.println("CANDIDATE TO DELETE");

}
```

Method is `static` and now return `void` for demo pourposes, but I will recommend to declare it like:

```
private boolean checkIfZeros(float[] simpleArray)
```

And call it inside an if that removes it or not:

```
if (!checkIfZeros(array))
    // delete
```

**NOTE:** This is for 1D array, if is what you need simply add new `for-loop` inside existing one to check the 2D... ask further info if you need.

Comment: Many thanks 
but i want to remove this arrays  also 
Iam sorry but i didn't under stand how  can i applay this demo on my code could you clear it more if you don't mind

Comment: first of all, I need to know where you get the data and how you manage it... if you can, please provide a full demo where we can reproduce your problem. second, this method check if an array is full of zeroes, so use it to check your arrays third: I'm sorry but your code is a real mess to get into it

Comment: Can you gave me just more time !

Comment: sure, just warn me when you edit your question ;) also, check the method I wrote to you and try to understand it in order to adapt it to you needs

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems are not the same in the 2 methods even if it's an out of bound in both cases.

Starting with the second method, the logic in the most inner loop where the zeros are checked, is wrong. The `index` (first dimension of `allVectors`) is incremented for each test of `input2[i1]`, which, depending on the size of this dim will overflow at some point. A proposed logic is

```
    for(int i=0;i<angle.getHeight();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<angle.getWidth();j++) {       
            //...

            boolean allZeros = true;
            for (int i1 = 0; allZeros && i1 < input2.length; i1++) {
                allZeros = (input2[i1] == 0);
            }
            // increment index only once input2 is tested
            if (allZeros) {
                allVectorsOfZeros[index++] = input2;
            }
            else
            {
                allVectors[index++] = input2;
            }
         }
      }
```

For the first method, I haven't spotted the actual `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`, but the code won't do what you expect. Correcting it may solve the error.

The problem comes from the way you remove the *zeros* vector from the list. In this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allVectors.size(); i++) {
   if (isZeros(allVectors.get(i))) {
       allVectors.remove(i);     // <= pb here
   }
}
```

If you read de javadoc for `public E remove(int index)`

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Since you loop from `0` to `allVectors.size()`, and assuming that you have 4 vectors, all full of zeros, you will remove

- the vector at index `0`, then the elements are shifted on the left, size is now 3
- the vector at index `1`, size is now 2.

You will effectively remove the *odd* index (in my example above) in the original vector and left with 2 vectors full of zeros but not removed. The solution is to start removing from the end of the list, then there is no element shift, or to use an iterator (no index) with `ListIterator#remove()`.

---

EDIT - Note that when you do:

```
float[][] allVectors = new float [numberOfPixels][binningNumber];
float[][] allVectorsOfZeros = new float [numberOfPixels][binningNumber];
```

you allocate a (numberOfPixels*binningNumber) 2d array. When further you do

```
allVectors[index++] =input2;
```

The allocated arrays for the second dimension are not used. There is no copy of the elements from `input2[]` to `allVectors[index][]`. And there is no *control* to see if the size of `input2` matches the initial size.
What's happening is merely `allVectors[index]` will reference `input2`. For instance, the following code works, even if the declared 2d dimension of `foo` is not used

```
   int [][] foo = new int[2][3];
   foo[0] = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
   foo[1] = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

Usually, you can declare the 2d dim as `[]`, array of unspecified length. Each element of the first dim contains `null`, e.g.

```
   int [][] foo = new int[2][];
   // foo[0][0] = 42; => NullPointException
```

or

```
   int [][] foo = new int[2][0];
   // foo[0][0] = 42; => ArrayOutOfBoundException
   // but foo[0].length == 0
```

This last way may be preferred since you don't need to test for `null` when looping, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < foo[i].length; j++) { 
      //...
   }
}
```